# make highlight with pdfIum pdfSearchManager

Tags: c#

I need to programmatically search pdf with pdfSearchManager and highlight the text. The code can make the search but with no highlight.
Plese see my code and correct me.

```
PdfSearchManager a = new PdfSearchManager(pdfRenderer1);
a.Reset();
a.MatchWholeWord = true;
a.HighlightAllMatches = true;
MessageBox.Show(a.Search(textBox1.Text).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

As we can see on [GitHub](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer/blob/master/PdfiumViewer/PdfSearchManager.cs) (if that is the right PdfSearchManager you're using)

`Search()` is a boolean so its only return `true` or `false` so it won't show you any text with `.ToString()`

*Search()* :

```
/// <summary>
/// Searches for the specified text.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">The text to search.</param>
/// <returns>Whether any matches were found.</returns>
```

It returns: **Whether** any matches were found
and not : **Matches** that were found

---

If you're trying to highlight the matches and not display them as I thought at the beginning then you should try using `a.UpdateHighlights()` ( I never used PdfSearchManager before but it might work)

Comment: Hmm, let me delve a further more.

Comment: I've added a second part to my answer in case I misunderstood you

Comment: From PdfSearchManager, the Search Method should return all the marker for the searched text . Now, how to make that marker visible in pdfiumViewer

Answer (score 0):

From PdfSearchManager source code :

```
public bool Search(string text)
        {
            Renderer.Markers.Clear();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                _matches = null;
                _bounds = null;
            }
            else
            {
                _matches = Renderer.Document.Search(text, MatchCase, MatchWholeWord);
                _bounds = GetAllBounds();
            }

            _offset = -1;

            UpdateHighlights();

            return _matches != null && _matches.Items.Count > 0;
        }
```

there is private method UpdateHighlights and AddMatch :

```
private void UpdateHighlights()
        {
            Renderer.Markers.Clear();

            if (_matches == null)
                return;

            if (_highlightAllMatches)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _matches.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    AddMatch(i, i == _offset);
                }
            }
            else if (_offset != -1)
            {
                AddMatch(_offset, true);
            }
        }

        private void AddMatch(int index, bool current)
        {
            foreach (var pdfBounds in _bounds[index])
            {
                var bounds = new RectangleF(
                    pdfBounds.Bounds.Left - 1,
                    pdfBounds.Bounds.Top + 1,
                    pdfBounds.Bounds.Width + 2,
                    pdfBounds.Bounds.Height - 2
                );

                var marker = new PdfMarker(
                    pdfBounds.Page,
                    bounds,
                    current ? CurrentMatchColor : MatchColor,
                    current ? CurrentMatchBorderColor : MatchBorderColor,
                    current ? CurrentMatchBorderWidth : MatchBorderWidth
                );

                Renderer.Markers.Add(marker);
            }
        }
```

I think the Search method had add all the marker from searched text.
Now, how to make it visible in pdfiumViewer.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out that i am referenced to wrong renderer.

my previous code was :
    `PdfSearchManager a = new PdfSearchManager(pdfRenderer1);`
where pdfRenderer1 is the name of **component** which i put on the Form

The code should be :
    `PdfSearchManager a = new PdfSearchManager(pdfViewer1.Renderer);`

The highlight searched text is run as expected.